I need to find all Nerode equivalence classes of the language abb*
I got so far:
I know that there are 4 classes (I built the smallest DFN) and that one of them ist [abb*]. I think the second one is [b*]. But I have no idea what the other two could be. I´m guessing that [ba*] is one of the missing ones. I testet so many possible words. Today I spent 4 hours on this and this is all I got.
I dont need a soution. I need just some words of the other classes or an Idea on how I could approach this problem.
Thank you so much in advants. Have a nice Weekend you all!

Build a DFA for the language.  Minimize the DFA.  Then each state of the DFA corresponds to an equivalence class.

Neither $b^*$ nor $ba^*$ are equivalence classes.
Denote $A = (Q, \delta, q_0, F)$ your minimal (complete) automaton. The Nerode equivalence classes are defined as $L_q = \{u\in \Sigma^* \mid \delta^*(q_0, u) = q\}$, for each $q\in Q$.
As an example, since there is no transition coming into the state $q_0$, that means that $L_{q_0} = \{\varepsilon\}$ is a class.

So one is just {ε}? I thougt they need to be infinit many elements in all of them. Thank you for this. abb* was right? And when I look at my DFA in need to find the RE of all qi´s?

I have solved It! Thank you so so much! Now I understand what we are doing. It was all just because of one misunderstanding. You are my hero!

@Apollocraftecrafte If that answered your question, you can accept this answer! Glad that helped.
